# Cannot read emails office365 using javaMail & IMAPS

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm facing an error using javaMail & IMAPS to read emails on email account of my company hosted in office 365.

I'm using this test class:

```
public class TestMail {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties props = System.getProperties();               
    props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable","true"); 
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "100000");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");

         try {
              Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
              session.setDebug(true);
              Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
              store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "my-name@mycompagny.com", "MY_PASSWORD");
              System.out.println(store);
              Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
              inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
              Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
              for(Message message:messages) {
                   System.out.println(message);
              }
    }  catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(2);
    }
}

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: disable AUTH=PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UABSADIAUAAyADYANABDAEEAMAAwADAANAAuAEYAUgBBAFAAMgA2ADQALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=my-name@mycompagny.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO LOGIN failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:661)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at com.afklm.bagdss.task.TestMail.main(TestMail.java:25)
```

Comment: Assuming your password is absolutely correct, have you asked your admin is IMAP is enabled for your domain?  If it has any additional security set up?  Do you have a special message in your inbox asking you to approve the login?

Comment: First, fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Why have you disabled PLAIN authentication?  Try removing that property setting.  If that doesn't help, try setting the property `mail.debug.auth` to "true" to see if you get any more useful information in the debug output (but don't post it, because it will contain your encoded password).